# How to subscribe and test Observable.of rxjs Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a function which returns a rxjs observable, but I cannot subscribe to it in any way. None of the subscribe method that I've tried are working.

`"rxjs": "6.5.4","@angular/core": "9.0.1"`

Function that i'm trying to test:

```
isNameValid(c: AbstractControl) {
    const searchResult = this.roles.filter((elem: any) => elem.name?.toLowerCase() === c.value?.toLowerCase());

    if (searchResult.length > 0) {
      c.get('name')?.setErrors({ nameTaken: true });
      return of({ matchError: 'nameTaken' });
    }
    return of(true);
  }
```

test:

```
it('should return invalid error if supplied name is taken', () => {
    const nameControl = new FormControl(mock[0].name);
    const isValid = component.isNameValid(nameControl);
    isValid.subscribe
      ({
        next: (result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
        },
        error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
        },
        complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
        }
        });
  });
```

What is the correct syntax of subscribing to the observable returned by `isNameValid`? Right now, with the pasted syntax(or anything else that I've tried) I cannot get the error free way of subscribing.

Should I write the test differently?

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
Observable.d.ts(51, 39): An argument for 'error' was not provided.
```

I've also tried:

`isValid.subscribe(response => {console.log(response})` which gives the same error.

Comment: Why are you passing an *object* to `.subscribe`? Doesn't it take up to three callbacks *positionally* (see e.g. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/interface/Subscribable#subscribe)? What *are* the errors? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited the question. That is already a minimal reproducible example. I want to access the value returned by the observable and compare it eventually, but I cannot get the subscribe syntax right.

Comment: @jonrsharpe AFAIK you can pass an Suscriber-Like object to it. You could use marbles to test. See https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing

Comment: With the output it is. `Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)` - you're only passing one, either an object (first example) or function (second). What happens if you pass 2-3 arguments?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo so it seems, but this is *TypeScript* complaining so I guess the types don't reflect that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's why I posted the question I cannot find the right 2-3 arguments syntax from which I can read the result and write the test

Comment: `.subscribe((result: any) => console.log(result), (err: any) => console.log(err), () => console.log('complete'))`? Did you look at the type in use to see what arguments it was expecting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I've tried that one as well. Gives back `No overload matches this call ....`

Comment: It's helpful to include the other things you've tried, so we avoid repeated suggestions that frustrate both parties. What type definition do you have for that method? Is it https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/types.ts#L41-L50? What *are* those overloads?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm sorry for not providing all the things that I've tried, but I've been trying for quite some time and forgot about some of them. An answer was posted which solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some TypeScript problem not being able to infer return value correctly.

To fix the problem, please provide type definition explicitly for `isNameValid` method:

```
isNameValid(c: AbstractControl): Observable<boolean | { matchError: string }> {
  // ...
}
```

Btw, you can pass an object to [`subscribe()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe-with-an-observer), this is completely valid.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Thank you. Never thought about that. I've been at this for a long time. This does indeed solve the issue.